# How to play sound on mobile in locked mode

Tags: html, mobile, web-push

I'm trying to play this sound on mobile locked mode.

```
<audio src="/sounds/sound.mp3">
<p>If you are reading this, it is because your
browser does not support the audio element.
</p>
</audio>
```

How can I do this?
Can anyone help me with the code?

Thanks

Comment: What's the error you're getting? Which phones and which browsers have you tried?

Comment: I have updated my question, I'm seaching the code